# Avoid duplicate calls after ThenLoadRelated() in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am facing a problem where I must duplicate a method call for reaching a proper data loading in Entity Framework.

```
// h = history
MyQuery.LoadRelated(myStore, h => h.Membership)
       .ThenLoadRelated(myStore, m => m.Type)
       .LoadRelated(myStore, h => h.Membership)
       .ThenLoadRelated(myStore, m => m.Owner);
```

I want to load the Membership Type and the Membership Owner. Both are dependent on `Membership`.

I have tried something like the following, but it throws an exception during execution time.

```
// h = history
MyQuery.LoadRelated(myStore, h => h.Membership)
       .ThenLoadRelated(myStore, m => new {m.Type, m.Owner});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No exception info. Unknown custom method LoadRelated. What do you expect ?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I am looking for beeing able to use something similar to the first peice of code but without Loading twice the same row.